# como faço para puxar o resultado de uma coluna dentro de uma string no mysql

Tags: mysql

exemplo :

```
select 
    case
        when campo = 1 then 'existe o resultado='aqui eu colocaria o nome da coluna da tabela 'fim da string'
        else 0
    end 
from banco.tabela;
```

como faria isso tem uma forma de concatenar?

Answer (score 4):

Para concatenar no `MySQL` tem que usar a função `CONCAT`, ficaria assim:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN campo = 1 THEN CONCAT('existe o resultado=', banco.tabela.coluna, 'fim da string')
        ELSE 0
    END 
FROM banco.tabela;
```

Veja mais sobre a função `CONCAT` [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).